# JavaScript inline variables used by external JavaScript file? (Variable Scope issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ops = {
        slideshow: {
            slices: 20,
            boxCols: 11,
            boxRows: 6,
            animSpeed: 750,
            pauseTime: 6000
        },
        tweets: {
            username: 'stigmahost',
            count: 6,
            refresh_interval: 120,
            auto_join_text_default: 'I said,',
            auto_join_text_ed: "I",
            auto_join_text_ing: "I am",
            auto_join_text_reply: "I replied to",
            auto_join_text_url: "I was looking at",
            just_now: 'Now',
            X_seconds_ago: '{x} seconds ago',
            about_a_minute_ago: 'About a minute ago',
            about_X_minutes_ago: 'About {x} minutes ago',
            about_an_hour_ago: 'About an hour ago',
            about_X_hours_ago: 'About {x} hours ago',
            about_a_day_ago: 'About a day ago',
            about_X_days_ago: 'About {x} ημέρες ago'
        },
        map:
        {
            latitude: 37.966667,
            longitude: 23.716667,
            zoom: 8
        }
    }
</script>
```

and **immediately** after that code I have that code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&sensor=true"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
```

Then from within the **js.js** file I try to use the **ops** variable but with no any luck. Do you have any idea why I cannot use the variable **ops** into the **js.js**.

Into js file I have use that code in order to determine the type of the ops variable:

```
console.dir(ops);
```

and in my Console I get the **undefined** result.

Have I did anything wrong ?

---

I did some progress. The js.js file is like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        console.dir(typeof ops);
        ...
        File code here
        ...
    }
);
```

The above code return in my console "undefined"

Now I have try that:

```
console.dir(typeof ops);

jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        console.dir(typeof ops);
        ...
        File code here
        ...
    }
);
```

and return in my Console, "Object" for the first try and "undefined" for the second typeof.

Can that help ?

Comment: i tryed the code (without the googleapis) and it seems to work fine, can you show us how you trying to access ops? i'm using chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getScript("js.js", function() {
    //declare ops-variable in here and use it
});
```

---

Without jquery:

```
var Loader = function () {

}
Loader.prototype = {
require: function (scripts, callback) {
    this.loadCount      = 0;
    this.totalRequired  = scripts.length;
    this.callback       = callback;

    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        this.writeScript(scripts[i]);
    }
},
loaded: function (evt) {
    this.loadCount++;

    if (this.loadCount == this.totalRequired && typeof this.callback == 'function') this.callback.call();
},
writeScript: function (src) {
    var self = this;
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = src;
    s.addEventListener('load', function (e) { self.loaded(e); }, false);
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(s);
}
}

 var l = new Loader();
l.require([
"js.js"
function() {
    // do same stuff in this callback
});
```

Comment: I cannot use that, because the jQuery library is include it into js.js file for speed optimization issue. Your answer upvoted from me because of the info ;) Thanks ...

Comment: @MerianosNikos I added a non jquery async solution. Maybe it can help

Comment: Do you know, what's wrong with the external variables in jQuery(document).read(.... ?

Comment: @MerianosNikos Is jquery loaded when you try to use your document ready function?

Comment: @MerianosNikos have you tried replacing it with `$(window).load(function() { });` ?

Comment: I just try it and nothing changed :(